# como lidar com NaN em Dataframe criado com list comprehension (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Como eu posso tirar esses `NaN` e deixar os títulos dos filmes, por qualquer um dos métodos de construção?

```py
import pandas as pd
rating_data = pd.read_csv('ml-25m/ratings.csv')
movies_data = pd.read_csv('ml-25m/movies.csv')['title']
k = pd.DataFrame(movies_data.head(10), index =[ i for i in  range(1,11)], columns = ['título'])

s = pd.Series(data = k['título'], index = k.index)
print(k)
print(s)
```

Comment: Uma variavel se chama rating_data e a outra movies_data?

Answer (score -1):

consegui dessa forma pelo Jupyter:

k = pd.DataFrame(movies_data.head(10).to_frame().title, index = [i for i in range(10)])
print(k)
s = pd.Series(data = k.title, index = k.index)
print(s)

consegue me explicar a diferença de sintaxe?